# Function Typing with constraint on Union

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
export type Command = { aggregateId: string }
export type AddTask = Command & { name: string, dueDate: Date }

export type Commands =
  | AddTask
  | RemoveTask
  | CompleteTask
  | ChangeDueDate

export type Event = { aggregateId: string }
export type TaskAdded = Event & { name: string, dueDate: Date }

export type Events =
  | TaskAdded
  | TaskRemoved
  | TaskCompleted
  | TaskDueDateChanged

export type CommandHandler<T extends Commands> = (command: T) => Events | DomainError
```

How can I annotate this `function` to be of type `CommandHandler<AddTask>`

```
export function AddTaskCommandHandler (command: AddTask): Events {
  const event: TaskAdded = { aggregateId: command.aggregateId, dueDate: command.dueDate, name: command.name }
  return event
}
```

Also I want to ensure I can only return an `Event` which is a member of the `Events` union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the function declaration as a `var` with an anonymous function value. Then explicitly type the var as `CommandHandler<AddTask>` and typescript will infer/typecheck the value.

```js
export var AddTaskCommandHandler: CommandHandler<AddTask> = function(command) {
    const event: TaskAdded = { aggregateId: command.aggregateId, dueDate: command.dueDate, name: command.name }
    return event
}
```

Here `command` is inferred to be `AddTask` and the return type is checked to be an `Events | DomainError`.

Comment: Maybe a bit more modern would be to use `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: I considered that but a function declaration behaves like a `var` and so it would be up to op if it acceptable to make the change to a `const` (or even `let` for that matter).